# Trouble using PyInstaller on Mac

Tags: python, linux, windows, macos, python-3.x

*Note: I am a very inexperienced at this. I just started using python this semester. Please bear with me when I am trying to describe things/dumb down your answers as much as you can because I don't yet understand a lot of this.

I am trying to create an executable file for a program that I have made in python v3.5. I would like to be able to distribute it to end users (I think that is the term... I just want people to be able to put in inputs and get outputs from my program without having to install python or an interpreter) on mac, windows, and I guess Linux (although I've never heard of that OS before I started doing this stuff... yes I know... that's probably embarrassing).

From what I have been able to gather thus far, PyInstaller seems to be the best way to do this. I am also fairly confident that I have managed to install it correctly (when I ask what version I have of it in my terminal, it responds with version 3.1.2 or something like that).

Now I am struggling with the next part. I am working my Mac (OS X El Capitan) and I just can't seem to find a good tutorial that shows/explains how to get to a executable. I have literally been search for days and have poured a silly amount of hours into this, but all the results that I find either go completely over my head or just give me error messages.

Any help that you could provide would be greatly appreciated. Am I even approaching this the correct way? Is an executable  the best way to share a python 3.5 program to a mass of end users??

At this point, if you guys can't come through I might have to give up... because I've already dumped at least 15 hours into this...

Thanks in advance -
Jamey

Answer (score 0):

PyInstaller has a pretty in depth manual with a section on how to use it to create executables which can be found here:

https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#using-pyinstaller

For most cases you'll generally use `pyinstaller myscript.py` which will create an executable inside a folder named dist.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've been able to get up to this point. And I have read the section called "using PyInstaller" I just can't figure what the heck they are talking about. This is what it reads...                                                                         The syntax of the pyinstaller command is:

pyinstaller [options] script [script ...] | specfile
In the most simple case, set the current directory to the location of your program myscript.py and execute:

Comment: What does that mean??

Comment: That is a typical "bash" or "command line" format. There are 4 parts: `function [options] input [inputs... ]`. `Function` is the program you want to run. `input` is a required input to that function. Anything in [ ] is optional, that is you don't have to put anything. Anything with ... means you can put multiple entries. In your case all you need is `pyinstaller myscript.py` where `pyinstaller` is the function and `myscript.py` is the input. You don't need any options and you are entering a single input, so the stuff inside `[ ]` and using `...` doesn't apply.